# Weird behaviour in MapReduce, values get overwritten

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been trying to implement the TfIdf algorithm using MapReduce in Hadoop. My TFIDF takes place in 4 steps (I call them MR1, MR2, MR3, MR4). Here are my input/outputs:

**MR1**: `(offset, line) ==(Map)==> (word|file, 1) ==(Reduce)==> (word|file, n)`

**MR2**: `(word|file, n) ==(Map)==> (file, word|n) ==(Reduce)==> (word|file, n|N)`

**MR3**: `(word|file, n|N) ==(Map)==> (word, file|n|N|1) ==(Reduce)==> (word|file, n|N|M)`

**MR4**: `(word|file, n|N|M) ==(Map)==> (word|file, n/N log D/M)`

Where n = number of (word, file) distinct pairs, N = number of words in each file, M = number of documents where each word appear, D = number of documents.

As of the MR1 phase, I'm getting the correct output, for example: `hello|hdfs://.....    2`

For the MR2 phase, I expect: `hello|hdfs://.......      2|192` but I'm getting `2|hello|hdfs://......    192|192`

I'm pretty sure my code is correct, every time I try to add a string to my "value" in the reduce phase to see what's going on, the same string gets "teleported" in the key part.

Example: `gg|word|hdfs://....    gg|192`

Here is my **MR1** code:

```
public class MR1 {
    /* Classe Map :
    *  Entree : (offset, line)
    *  Sortie : (word|file, 1)
    *  Sends 1 for each word per line.
    */
    static class MR1Mapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable > {
        public void map (LongWritable key, Text value, Context contexte)
                       throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // Recuperation du nom du fichier associe au "split" 
            FileSplit split = (FileSplit) contexte.getInputSplit();
            String fileName = split.getPath().toString();
    
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "' \t:,;:!?./-_()[]{}\"&%<>");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String word = tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase();
                contexte.write(new Text(word + "|" + fileName), new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }
    } 
    
    /* Class Reducer : compte le nombre d'occurrence total par mot/fichier
    * Entree : (word|file, x)
    * Sortie : (word|file, n)
    */
    public static class MR1Reducer extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable < IntWritable > values, Context contexte) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val:values) {
                sum += val.get();
            } 
            contexte.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    } 
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(args.length + "(" + args[0] + "," + args[1] + ")");
            System.err.  println("Usage : MR1 <source> <destination>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MR1.class);
    
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
        job.setMapperClass(MR1Mapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass (MR1Reducer.class) ;
        job.setReducerClass(MR1Reducer.class);
    
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Here is my **MR2** code:

```
public class MR2 {
    /* Map : on isole le nom du fichier.
    * Entree : (word|file, n)
    * Sortie : (file, word|n)
    */
    static class MR2Mapper extends Mapper <Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map (Text key, Text value, Context contexte) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String skey = key.toString () ;
            String word = skey.substring (0, skey.indexOf ("|")) ;
            String fileName = skey.substring (skey.indexOf ("|")+1) ;
            contexte.write (new Text (fileName), new Text (word + "|" + value)) ;
        }
    }
    
    /* Reduce : on somme le nombre d'occurence de chaque mot du fichier
    * Entree : (file, word|n)
    * Sortie : (word|file, n|N)
    */
    public static class MR2Reducer extends Reducer <Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce (Text key, Iterable <Text> values, Context contexte) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int N = 0 ;
    
            // les iterateurs sont utilisable qu'une seule fois. Donc il faut
            // garder les valeurs dans une arraylist pour les reparcourir.
            ArrayList <String> altmp = new ArrayList <String> () ;
        
            // 1ere boucle : calcul de la somme totale des mots
            for (Text val : values) {
                String sval = val.toString () ;
                String sn = sval.substring (sval.indexOf ("|")+1) ;
                int n = Integer.parseInt (sn) ;
            
                altmp.add (val.toString ()) ;
                N += n ;
            }
    
            // 2eme boucle : calcul de la somme totale des mots
            Iterator <String> it = altmp.iterator () ;
            while (it.hasNext ()) {
                String val = it.next () ;
                String sval = val.toString () ;
                String word = sval.substring (0, sval.indexOf ("|")) ;
                String sn = sval.substring (sval.indexOf ("|")+1) ;
                int n = Integer.parseInt (sn) ;
            
                // I tried to replace n with "gg" here, still same teleporting issue
                contexte.write (new Text (word + "|" + clef.toString ()), new Text (n + "|" + N)) ; 
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String args []) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println (args.length + "("+args [0] + "," +args [1] + ")") ;
            System.err.println ("Usage : MR2 <source> <destination>") ;
            System.exit (-1) ;
        }
    
        Job job = new Job () ;
        job.setJarByClass (MR2.class) ;
    
        // Le fichier HDFS a utiliser en entree
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath (job, new Path (args [0])) ;
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath (job, new Path (args [1])) ;
    
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    
        job.setMapperClass (MR2Mapper.class) ;
        job.setCombinerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;
        job.setReducerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;
    
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass (Text.class) ;
        job.setMapOutputValueClass (Text.class) ;
    
        job.setOutputKeyClass (Text.class) ;
        job.setOutputValueClass (Text.class) ;
    
        System.exit (job.waitForCompletion (true) ? 0 : 1) ;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Combiner's fault. You are specifying in the driver class that you want to use `MR2Reducer` both as a Combiner and a Reducer in the following commands:

```
job.setCombinerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;
job.setReducerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;
```

However, a Combiner is running within the range of a `Map` instance, while a Reducer is operating in series after the execution of all the Mappers. By using a Combiner, you are essentially putting `MR2Reducer` to execute right after the execution of each individual Mapper task, so it calculates `N` and splits the composite value of the given key-value input within each Mapper task range.

This basically results in the `Reduce` phase kicking off by having input of the `(word|file, n|N)` key-value pair schema (aka the output of a `MR2Reducer` task *before* the `Reduce` phase) instead of the desired `(file, word|n)` schema. By unknowingly using the false schema, you falsely split the composite value and the output key-value pairs look wonky, wrong, and/or reverse.

To fix this, you can either:

- create a custom Combiner that will have the same commands as your current `MR2Reducer`, and then change your `MR2Reducer` class to receive key-value pairs in the `(word|file, n|N)` schema (**not recommended**, as it will probably negate all the benefits in terms of scalability and execution time, and will only make your MapReduce job more complicated that it can be), or
- delete or comment out the `job.setCombinerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;` line from your driver class to keep things simple and functional, so you can built from there in the future.

To showcase this, I used your `MR1`, `MR2` classes locally on my machine, deleted the `job.setCombinerClass (MR2Reducer.class) ;` line and used [this](https://github.com/Coursal/Hadoop-Examples/tree/main/TopWords/metamorphosis) input stored in HDFS to verify that the output key-value pairs are as desired. Here is a snippet of the output after the execution:

```
balance|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt    1|661
suppress|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt   1|661
back|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt       4|661
after|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt      1|661
suspicious|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt 2|661
swang|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt      2|661
swinging|hdfs://localhost:9000/user/crsl/metamorphosis/05.txt   1|661
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer. That solved my issue and helped me to understand more.